# specflow+ example test on mac os (x64)

Tags: c#, .net, specflow

I am running specflow+ example test from [here](https://github.com/SpecFlowOSS/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples/tree/master/SeleniumWebTest/TestApplication.UiTests)  on mac catalina( x64) using Visual Studio for mac but I get this error

`ExecutionThreadApartmentState option not supported for framework: .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1.`

Since `apartmentState` property is not supported on mac as mentioned [here](https://specflow.org/plus/documentation/Execution/)

I tried by removing `apartmentState` from `<execution>` element and also tried removing the whole `<execution>` element from `Default.srprofile`  but still get same error in test results output. (test just keeps on running. Upon cancelling shows error in test output)

Tried `x64` in platform settings in build but I get below when try to run test

`Test run will use DLL(s) built for framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1 and platform X86. Following DLL(s) do not match framework/platform settings.
TestApplication.UiTests.dll is built for Framework .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1 and Platform X64.`

Is it that the example tests mentioned above can not be run on mac os (x64) ? or am I missing some other thing?

**EDIT**
I installed and targeted .net core 3.0 and the still get

`ExecutionThreadApartmentState option not supported for framework: .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0.`

**EDIT2**
The error I see in the logs is below. I think the above error about `ExecutionThreadApartmentState` may be just a warning because I still see it in test output

```
2020-04-29T13:55:54.5764790-04:00:Executing test executor at '/usr/bin/dotnet' 'exec "/Users/../Desktop/../projects/specflow/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples-master/SeleniumWebTest/TestApplication.UiTests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0/SpecFlowPlusRunner/netcoreapp3.0/TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Executor.anycpu.netcoreapp3_0.dll" --remoteRunnerPid 37116 --uniqueId "2020-04-29T135554" --outputFolder "/Users/../Desktop/../projects/specflow/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples-master/SeleniumWebTest/TestApplication.UiTests/obj/TestResults" --callbackPort 32770 --loggerPort 32771' in '/Users/../Desktop/../projects/specflow/SpecFlow.Plus.Examples-master/SeleniumWebTest/TestApplication.UiTests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.0'
2020-04-29T13:55:54.6057600-04:00:System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): No such file or directory
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Execution.OutOfProc.OutProcExecutorManager.StartProcess(ExecutorProcessInfo executorProcessInfo)
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.VsOutProcExecutorManager.StartProcess(ExecutorProcessInfo executorProcessInfo)
   at TechTalk.SpecRun.Framework.Execution.OutOfProc.StreamJsonRPC.OutOfProcessTestAssemblyExecutorHost.Initialize(Int32 threadId, ITestExecutionManager executionManager, IAssemblyReference testAssembly, ITestLogger currentLogger, String testAssemblyFullPath, String testAssemblyConfigFilePath, TestExecutionConfiguration testExecutionConfiguration, String target)
```

Comment: Try deleting the .vs folder in the root of the project folder.  Re-open the solution and see if this helps.

Comment: @youzer I tried that way but same results

Comment: I still have this issue, does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Literally just ran into this myself and after trying to be smart and figure out the problem for a little bit I just exited and opened VS again and it went away.

note that I had been messing with the version of the EF used multiple times upgrade and downgrading the version. I settled on the same version I started with and also restored packages many times.

Comment: After seeing your comment,  I tried this again. But I am still seeing the same error as I mentioned above in my Edit2 . Do you any idea , how to resolve that or any pointers ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, not yet;) but I got this error too. and I found that it happened because a Class variable I declared in the Test - in its constructor there was a call to a method of an object stored in a field of the class with I/O from the Console.
when I removed the call from the constructor the tests (unit test) could run ok again.